# 'Merging' neural networks python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I've created 2 neural networks in Python with tensorflow, one is a simple chatbot and the other takes user input, and identifies a search query from the input, for example text input is "please look up what is a computer on google" and it outputs "what is a computer", no matter how you write it, pretty simple.

But this happens, first the user input goes through the chatbot neural network, once it identifies is a "search" what the user wants, then it passes through the other neural network, but how could I make this process happen in one single neural network?

My training data has this format (just the idea, *not exacly the same*):

```
{"intents": [
    {"tag": "search",
     "patterns": ["look up", "search", "investigate"],
     "responses": [""]
```

How can I shape my training data so that these two processes can happen in one neural network instead of two?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.